# What real values of $c$ makes these two vectors linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I had a question from my homework Friday night which stumped me.

It reads, verbatim

**Find all real values of $c$ such that the vectors**
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2\\c \\0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}c\\c+3 \\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**are linearly independent.**

I got stumped by this question; after trying to row reduce, I got

\begin{bmatrix}
2c &c^2  & |0 \\ 
 0&  -\frac{1}{2}c^2+c+3& |0 \\ 
 0&  0& |0
\end{bmatrix}

I wasn't sure what to do at this point. I see the two quadratics; I'm just unsure of what to do and why.

Comment: Hint: two vectors $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are linearly independent if $a \times b \neq 0$ (cross product).

Comment: The vectors are effectively $2$-vectors; just evaluate the two-by-two determinant.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the vectors are linearly dependent ie.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2\\c \\0
\end{bmatrix}=\lambda \begin{bmatrix}c\\c+3 \\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $\lambda \neq 0$. So $c^2 = 2(c+3)$ ie. $c=1 \pm \sqrt{7}$. And if $c=1 \pm \sqrt{7}$ the vectors are linearly dependent. So the vectors are linealy independent iff $c \in \Bbb R - \{1\pm \sqrt{7}\}$.

You can also use row-reduction: let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & c/2 \\
0 & c+3-c^2/2
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and use the fact that the vectors are linearly independent iff $\ker A = \{0\}$.